# How to get g++ assembly code instructions addresses

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++, masm

How do I get assembly code instructions addresses using g++,
I can print the assembly code from g++ using the following command

```
g++ -S -masm=intel
```

I get the the assembly code but it doesn't include the instruction address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-S` switch causes `g++` to emit the assembly it sends to the assembler. This is not a dump of an object and thus doesn't have addresses.

To get a dump of the object `g++` generates, first compile into an object file:

```
g++ -c foo.cpp
```

Then use `objdump` to dump the object file:

```
objdump -d -Mintel foo.o
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for ages for the solution.